# While fetching, the core data never works

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit

Since two days, I've been dissatisfied with core data, and I'm not sure why three of my devices (simulators) never sync data together. It was functioning last week but is no longer working this week. What went wrong with me? I've already signed in with my Apple ID on my simulator devices, restarted devices, and so on, and none of them function. I have "Reload Database" enabled in the options, but I have to click it every 5 minutes to an hour, and the database is never updated. I searched stackoverflow and google, but neither helped. I've already switched from development to production on cloudKit, and all of my databases are still not synchronizing.

AppDelegate:

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "How_s_Your_Day_")
    container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy
    container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

Startup, from tabbar view

```
class TheTabbars: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "How_s_Your_Day_")
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (_, error) in
            guard let error = error as NSError? else { return }
            fatalError("###\(#function): Failed to load persistent stores:\(error)")
        })


        nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(createDatabase), name: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange, object: container.persistentStoreCoordinator)
    }
}
```

Fetching my database:

```
func createDatabase() {
    do { theJournalData = try contextDataCore.fetch(The_journal_data.fetchRequest()) } catch { }
    do { theHabitList = try contextDataCore.fetch(The_habit_list.fetchRequest()) } catch { }
    do { thePhotoData = try contextDataCore.fetch(The_photo_data.fetchRequest()) } catch { }
    do { theMealsData = try contextDataCore.fetch(The_meal_plan.fetchRequest()) } catch { }
    do { thePlaceData = try contextDataCore.fetch(The_places.fetchRequest()) } catch { }
}
```

To reload the database, press the button

```
@objc func reloadTheDatabase() {
    createDatabase()
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I recently discovered two things...first, should I delete the NSPersistentCloudKitContainer in tabber viewdidload? Second, I recently discovered that it will only operate on actual devices, not simulators.

Comment: Error: <CKError 0x6000008c2d00: "Partial Failure" (2/1011); "Failed to modify some record zones"; partial errors: {
 com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone:__defaultOwner__ = <CKError 0x60000081dbf0: "Internal Error" (1/5000); "Failed to sync user keys">
}>